# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in stanford corenlp

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I have downloaded Stanford corenlp Python wrapper.I 've done the installation as given under a [link](https://github.com/brendano/stanford_corenlp_pywrapper) .

When I run this code

```
>>> from stanford_corenlp_pywrapper import CoreNLP
>>> proc = CoreNLP("pos", corenlp_jars=["/home/sw/corenlp/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-04-20/*"])
```

I have changed the jar location as below:

```
proc = CoreNLP("pos", corenlp_jars=["/media/pglab1-uni2/1EF20A75F20A5207/Anaconda2/stanford_corenlp_pywrapper-master/*"])
```

But I get a error as follows:

```
INFO:CoreNLP_PyWrapper:mode given as 'pos' so setting annotators: tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma
INFO:CoreNLP_PyWrapper:Starting java subprocess, and waiting for signal it's ready, with command: exec java -Xmx4g -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -cp '/media/pglab1-uni2/1EF20A75F20A5207/Anaconda2/stanford_corenlp_pywrapper-master/stanford_corenlp_pywrapper/lib/*:/media/pglab1-uni2/1EF20A75F20A5207/Anaconda2/stanford_corenlp_pywrapper-master/*'      corenlp.SocketServer --outpipe /tmp/corenlp_pywrap_pipe_pypid=11181_time=1455081808.61  --configdict '{"annotators": "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma"}'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP
    at corenlp.JsonPipeline.initializeCorenlpPipeline(JsonPipeline.java:206)
    at corenlp.SocketServer.main(SocketServer.java:102)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

Please help me with the error

Comment: What jar files did you put in the `Anaconda2/stanford_corenlp_pywrapper-master/` folder? That error makes it seem like you are missing one or more

Comment: Note, this is a python **wrapper** around a java library. You have to both install Java 8 **and** [download and extract CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html), neither of which, you mentioned doing. You just said you installed this `stanford_corenlp_pywrapper`

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that I see your other question that the Github page says "Does not currently work on Windows"

Answer (score 0):

Two Reason can be for this:

1. You don’t have jar which contains called class or
2. Your jar is corrupted.

**1. You don’t have jar**
Add these maven dependencies to get all jar related to Standford CoreNLP.

```
 <properties>
    <stanford.corenlp.version>3.9.1</stanford.corenlp.version>
 </properties>

  <dependencies>

       <dependency> 
           <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
           <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
           <version>${stanford.corenlp.version}</version>
       </dependency> 
       <dependency> 
           <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
           <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
           <version>${stanford.corenlp.version}</version>
           <classifier>models</classifier> 
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**2. Your jar is corrupted**

Simply go to .m2 folder and remove all jars of Standford NLP. Again download jar from central repo.

**3.** if you are not using maven then check that is your jar is added to classpath or not?

Originally Answered here:
https://interviewbubble.com/solved-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-edu-stanford-nlp-parser-lexparser-lexicalizedparser/